# ASP.NET Core MVC - Sign-in with Microsoft

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I'm working on a project where the user needs to sign in with a Microsoft account registered in the Azure AD of the company to use the website, the problem is that we don't have access to the directory or the credentials so we need to get all the information needed through the user so that we can use other services such as Microsoft Graph. I don't know if it's possible, and if so, how can I implement all that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need access to the directory, either by yourself or you need to engage an admin of the tenant.

To be able to authenticate users for your App and acquire tokens to call services such as MS Graph, you need to create an app registration on the specific directory.

Take a look at the below .NET Core Web App sample from MS, where this is explained in detail:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/README.md